# Copying axis limits from one subplot ('equal' aspect) to another

Tags: matplotlib

In a figure with 2x2 subplots, I need both the subplots on the right to share the x-axis, but the ones on the left not to share their axis. In addition, I need the subplot that is determining the x-axis limits to have 'equal' aspect ratio. I tried this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 9))

# Subplot [0,1]    
ax[0,1].axis('equal') 
ax[0,1].plot(...)
[xmin01, xmax01, ymin01, ymax01] = self.ax[0,1].axis() 

# Subplot [1,1]
ax[1,1].plot(...)
ax[1,1].set_xlim(left=xmin01, right=xmax01)
```

This is not working: the limits of the x-axis returned by `axis()` are near the data limits and are not the real limits shown in the graphed subplot. Changing the position of `ax[0,1].axis('equal')` after the `plot` command has no effect. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the pyplot source code I discovered that `axis('equal')` is calling the method  `set_aspect()`. This latter method is modifying the variable `self._aspect` but it is not further updating anything related! Then, I looked for and found the method that is really updating the aspect ratio: it is named `apply_aspect()`. So, it doesn't seem very elegant, but at least my problem is solved as shown:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(12, 9))

# Subplot [0,1]    
ax[0,1].axis('equal') 
ax[0,1].plot(...)
ax[0,1].apply_aspect()
[xmin01, xmax01, ymin01, ymax01] = self.ax[0,1].axis() 

# Subplot [1,1]
ax[1,1].plot(...)
ax[1,1].set_xlim(left=xmin01, right=xmax01)
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that you just need to call `draw` after calling `set_aspect`.

Comment: The reason is that `matplotlib` is lazy and puts of doing anything until it _has_ to and this includes updating limits.